# Does it matter what object's transform the TransformPoint() method is attached to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

Does it matter what object's transform the [TransformPoint()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) method is attached to, since it's supposed to return a world space position? For example given the following structure:

- Obj1

  - ChildObj1
- Obj2

Doing `Obj1.transform.TransformPoint(Obj2.transform.position)` should return the same thing as `ChildObj1.transform.TransformPoint(Obj2.transform.position)` regardless of Obj1 and ChildObj1's positions.

Is this correct? If so, what am I missing? Why does the TransformPoint have to be attached to an object's transform?

Comment: The given point is converted from the according transforms local space coordinates into world space coordinates .. so obviously it matters which transform you call it on! Fully  depends ofcourse on your scene setup since it will return the same for all transforms that have the same transformations ....

Answer (score 2):

[TransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) takes in a Vector3 and returns a Vector3. All it does is convert a point from localSpace to WorldSpace. Since your example shows that Obj2 is not a child of Obj1, there will likely be confusion.

Let's say the following:

- Obj1 is at (5,0,0) in World position
- ChildObj1 is at (8,0,0) in World position, which is (3,0,0) in Local position (because it is 3 x-units higher than Obj1.
- Obj2 is at (6,0,0) in World position

Here is how the code shakes out for the above scenario:

```
Vector3 point1 = Obj1.transform.TransformPoint(Obj2.transform.position);  
//point1 = (11,0,0)
Vector3 point2 = ChildObj1.transform.TransformPoint(Obj2.transform.position) 
//point2 = (14,0,0)
```

The important thing to note here is that transform.position returns world position. If you were to use transform.LocalPosition where Obj2 is a a root object (localPosition = 0,0,0), then this would be the outcome:

```
Vector3 point1 = Obj1.transform.TransformPoint(Obj2.transform.localPosition);  
//point1 = (5,0,0)
Vector3 point2 = ChildObj1.transform.TransformPoint(Obj2.transform.localPosition) 
//point2 = (8,0,0)
```

Comment: Okay, so using an object's `transform.position` as the arg in `TransformPoint()` is a mistake because `transform.position` is already global. And even more confusingly, root objects have a localPosition of (0,0,0)!

Comment: And from what I gather, the conclusion is that `TransformPoint()` does NOT simply get an object's *global* position, but instead it translates the object's position relative to another object from local to *WorldSpace units*...

Comment: Is it not possible to just get the global coordinates of a vector without using another object as a reference point? I just want to global, absolute, position of a vector that's been through a complex series of transforms.

Comment: A Vector is neither global nor local. A Vector is just a struct to hold data. Transform.position is global, Transform.localPosition is local. Please provide more detail on what you're trying to accomplish by sharing your code that has a series of complex transforms @A__